# Много балунов на яндекс карте с ховером

Tags: javascript, html, css, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Вот так подключаю яндекс карту

```
                           <script type="text/javascript">
                                var myMap;
                                ymaps.ready(function () {
                                    myMap = new ymaps.Map("YMapsID", {
                                        center: [55.76, 37.64],
                                        zoom: 10
                                    });
                                    var myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();
                                    myCollection.add(new ymaps.Placemark([37.61, 55.75]));
                                    myCollection.add(new ymaps.Placemark([13.38, 52.51]));
                                    myCollection.add(new ymaps.Placemark([30.30, 50.27]));
                                    myCollection.events
                                        .add("mouseenter", function () {
                                            myCollection.options.set("preset", "twirl#redIcon");
                                        })
                                        .add("mouseleave", function () {
                                            myCollection.options.unset("preset");
                                        });
                                    myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);
                                    myMap.setBounds(myCollection.getBounds());
                                });

                            </script>
                            <div id="YMapsID" style="width: 450px; height: 350px;"></div>
```

Вот макет из Фотошопа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такой эффект при ховере с текстом в таком белом блоке.

Comment: по клику или именно ховеру?

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_html

Comment: лучше по клику.

Comment: вариант выше tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_html не устраивает?